# $E(XY)=E(X^2)$ when X and Y are independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be independent random variables and follows the same distribution. Then

$E(XY)=E(X^2).$

This is what my textbook uses to solve a problem. But I have never seen it before, it does not make sense to me right now.

---

**Edit** The original probelm was this:
Let X and Y be independent random variables that follows an Exponential distribution with parameter 1. Define Z=X+Y. Calculate the correlation coefficient of X and Z.

note to self: exam # 20120522

Comment: Maybe I can do like this: $$E(XY)=\int \int xy f_{XY}(x,y) dxdy= \int xf_X(x)dx \int yf_Y(y)dy$$

Comment: It does not make sense, as $X^2 \geq 0$, while $XY$ might be negative (e.g. take $X$ and $Y$ to be $1$ and $-1$ with equal probabilities).

Comment: edited question: X and Y are non-negative. See "The original probelm was this..."

Comment: Well, for exponential distributions we have $\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1} \neq \frac{2}{1^2} = \mathbb{E}(X^2)$. Perhaps it was $(\mathbb{E}X)^2$?

Comment: Which textbook says that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is not correct: Let $X,Y$ be independent Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Then $$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$$ but $$\mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y) = \mathbb{E}(X) \cdot \mathbb{E}(Y)=0.$$

---

Concerning your edit: Using a similar argumentation, it is not difficult to see that $$\mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y) = \mathbb{E}(X) \cdot \mathbb{E}(Y) \stackrel{X \sim Y}{=} (\mathbb{E}(X))^2$$ Since $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$, the latter equals $1$. Note that $$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = 2 \neq 1 = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y).$$

Comment: The book says E(XZ)=...=3 thus corr coeff = 1/sqrt(2).

Comment: How does one solve the original problem of finding corr coeff?

Comment: As already mentioned, $\mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=2$; hence, $\mathbb{E}(Z \cdot X) = 3$ by definition of $Z$. (It is important to know the moments of the exponential distributions, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Mean.2C_variance.2C_moments_and_median).)

Comment: Great, got it now.